# ¿Como actualizar mi modelo EF cuando hay cambios en la DB?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Estoy realizando un aplicación API en la cual realice un `Scaffold-DbContext` por que ya tenia creado mis tablas en mi BD, realice cambios en la BD, pero para actualizar mis modelos en mi proyecto se hace de la misma manera con `Update-database` o como se realizaria ?

Comment: Si estas utilizando database first, tienes que hacer el scaffold otra vez y recrearlo, guarda el comando que usas para que no te genere distintos nombres de clases y demas.

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias! Entonces volver a utilizar el mismo comando. Entonces el `Update-database` es para las migraciones, no ?